# MYSQL Cursor with buffered and prepared python

Tags: python, mysql

I am getting this error `ValueError: Cursor not available with given criteria: buffered, prepared` when trying to do `cur = conn.cursor(buffered=True, prepared=True)` I would like to create a cursor with prepared and buffered

version `mysql.connector.__version__ = '8.0.30'`

somewhat reproducable answer?

```
conn = mysql.connector.connect()
cur = conn.cursor(buffered=True, prepared=True)
cur.execute(stmt, (self.email, self.password,))
uid = cur.fetchone()
```

Comment: I don't see any source code in this question that I could try a test run on. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: `prepared` is not available until version 1.1.2 of the Connector.  What version are you using?

Comment: @J_H Please note you must setup a test enviroment with MYSQL thus in this case it would be impossible although this is the closest i can go......

Comment: @TimRoberts please check updated answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`prepared` cannot be used with any other parameters.  If you need `prepared`, you'll need to remove `buffered`.

Comment: Is there other ways to prepare a stmt then???

Comment: Sure, just remove `buffered=True`.  Do you understand what a prepared statement is in MySQL?  Based on your question, I'm guessing you don't really need it.  You can use `executemany` with an ordinary cursor.

Answer (score 0):

A Buffered cursor will fetch all rows. Use a Prepared/Unbuffered cursor and use fetchall in your code.